# How much memory array of objects in c# consumes?

Tags: c#, arrays, memory

Suppose that we have previously instantiated three objects A, B, C from class D 
now an array defines as below:
D[] arr = new D[3];
arr[0]=A;
arr[1]=B;
arr[2]=C;

does array contains references to objects or has separate copy?

Comment: References since they are objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# distinguishes *reference types* and *value types*.

A **reference type** is declared using the word **class**. Variables of these types contain references, so an array will be an array of references to the objects. Each reference is 4 bytes (on a 32-bit system) or 8 bytes (on a 64-bit system) large.

A **value type** is declared using the word **struct**. Values of this type are copied every time you assign them. An array of a value type contains copies of the values, so the size of the array is the size of the struct times the number of elements.

Normally when we say “object”, we refer to instances of a *reference type*, so the answer to your question is “yes”, but remember the difference and make sure that you don’t accidentally create a large array of a large struct.

Comment: Objects in C# have a default size. Also, Array has a length field. So for example, an int[100] wouldn't be 400 bytes only, it would be 424 bytes on a 64-bit machine. Also, the final padding, as sizes must be in blocks, and each block is 64 bytes, so an int[99] is also 424 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

An array of reference types only contains references.

In a 32 bit application references are 32 bits (4 bytes), and in a 64 bit application references are 64 bits (8 bytes). So, you can calculate the approximate size by multiplying the array length with the reference size. (There are also a few extra bytes for internal variables for the array class, and some extra bytes are used for memory management.)

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the memory occupied by an array using WinDBG + SOS (or PSSCOR2). IIRC, an array of reference types is represented in memory by its length, followed by references to its elements, i.e. it's exact size is `PLATFORM_POINTER_SIZE * (array.Length + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

The array is made out of pointers (32bit or 64bit) that points to the objects. An object is a reference type, only value types are copied to the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

As @Yves said it has references to the objects. The array is a block of memory as it as in C.
So it size is sizeof(element) * count + the amount of memory needed by oop.